# Catch go.microsoft from Visual Studio Performance Webtest

Tags: visual-studio-2010, performance

For my (performance) webtest I am using Visual Studio 2010. I perform this test from different domains and machines. Not all machines have access to the internet (except the preferred domain), however sometimes the test wants to call go.microsoft.com. Is there a way to catch this from the results (so it will not give an exception and failed result).

I tried changing the hosts file, however this is not possible on all environments. Any other solutions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this with a NoFollow of redirects in the performance script, however if there are other possibilities I would be glad to hear them